# plotting train_test_split while maintining their indices

Tags: python, matlab, plot, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to plot the train_test _split while maintaining the indices, here is my code.

```
#df.insert(0, 'x', range(0, 0 + len(df)))

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y,
                                             test_size = .1)

regressor = RandomForestClassifier()

regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)

plt.plot(X_train,y_pred_train,'bo')


plt.show()
```

It seems like the y_pred are plotting against the incorrect x_axis value as there is a huge gap in the middle of the data and some overlapping

How can I make the corresponding **x_value** of the **y_pred** and **y_pred_train** be in their original position from the data frame.

Comment: How about using `X_test` instead of `df[x]`?

Comment: Please share some samples of your data

Comment: Then share the code to generate those

Comment: @VivekKumar check new update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to include the index in the plot. usually y will be represented as the colour of each point. here is how to do so

```
plt.scatter(X_test.index,X_test.values,c=y_predict_test)
plt.show()
```

here is an a random example 
[image]

the pointes coloured as yellow belong to class0 and points coloured in purple belong to class 1

Comment: what does the c stand for here ? @sgDysregulation

Comment: c stands for color, which basically assign each point a colour based on the values in y